# How to parse xml element to primitive types?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

I have this xml:

```
<order>
    <id_address_delivery>4</id_address_delivery>
</order>
```

and java class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "order")
public static class Order
{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id_address_delivery")
    public String id_address_delivery;
}
```

When I try to parse xml with code:

```
XmlMapper XmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
XmlMapper.readValue(xml, Order.class);
```

I getting the error : **Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token**

How to correct deserialize xml element to primitive type?

Comment: Also `XmlMapper XmlMapper = new XmlMapper()` does not make sense. It should be at least `xmlMapper` (first letter lowercase) and `xmlMapper.readValue(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Could you confirm that the variable "cls" is Order.class? I get the error you reported if cls is String.class but that is not the correct approach as you are parsing the <order> element not the <id_address_delivery> element.

Do you have any bespoke configuration that might be causing the problem? Perhaps dodgy whitespace - try removing the whitespace completely?

My code ...

```
public class Jackson {

    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "order")
    private static class Order
    {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id_address_delivery")
        public String id_address_delivery;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Order order = mapper.readValue("<order>\n\t<id_address_delivery>4</id_address_delivery></order>", Order.class);

        System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(order, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE));
    }
}
```

produces

{"id_address_delivery":"4"}

Comment: Radik, have you rerun your code since changing it to use Order.class rather than the _cls_ variable? The error message does seem to be indicating that is the problem.